# PhpStorm select text till end of file

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

How can I select all code from caret to end of file with a keyboard shortcut? I couldn't find anything in the documentation

I'm using PhpStorm 2017.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cannot speak for Ubuntu .. but here on Windows the standard <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + End</kbd> works just fine.

---

If anything -- `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`. Find there `Editor Actions | Move Caret to Text End with Selection` action and see what shortcut it has (you may change it to another one if needed).

[image]
*(here I've used `Find action by Shortcut` functionality to quickly locate that action)*